# Re-map keys on keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard

I know how to re-map my modifier keys, so my caps lock can act as a ctrl key, for example.

I'm wondering if there's a way to re-map they dash/underscore key (next to +/=). Instead of it producing a dash or hyphen, I'd like it to produce an em dash. And pressing shift+opt+dash (the current shortcut for an em dash) key would produce a normal dash.

Based on Karl's answer, I tried using BetterTouchTool (as Global shortcuts and also TextEdit specifically), but remapped keypresses just seem to be ignored.

[image]

Comment: Change keyboard language setting?

Comment: [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) should be able to do that (paid). You could also try [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) or [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) (both free) but I don't have experience with those.

Answer (score 4):

BetterTouchTool ( http://blog.boastr.net ) can re-map arbitrary keys. Under preferences, select the "keyboard" tab, then "+add New Shortcut", click in the "Keyboard Shortcut" then type the key you want to change. Then select "Trigger Other Keyboard Shortcut" and type in shift-opt-dash.

There might be simpler ways just for keyboard remapping, but BTT can do lots of other things too.

Hope this helps,

Karl

Comment: great idea but unfortunately that didn't work. I posted a screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Install and launch [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). In the menubar open the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences. Then hit the tab "Misc & Uninstall" and "Open private.xml"

Paste the following lines into the opened xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
      <name>Swap Minus and Alt+Shift+Minus</name>
      <identifier>remap.minus_and_optionlshiftlminus</identifier>
      <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__ 
        KeyCode::MINUS, ModifierFlag::NONE,
        KeyCode::MINUS, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
      </autogen>
      <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::MINUS, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
        KeyCode::MINUS,
      </autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

and save the file.

Return to the tab "Change Key", hit "ReloadXML"  and enable "Swap Minus and Alt+Shift+Minus". It should be the first entry listed.

If you are left-handed you may replace _L by _R in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Caps lock key is a more special key and a lot of the key remapping program have trouble working with it.
I personally use the app **Seil** (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en), previously called PCKeyboardHack to *remap my caps lock to backspace*.

Here's a screenshot of the setting page in **Seil**.
[image: Seil setting page]

Also, as shown in the description above, you also need to set caps lock to **No Action** in Mac OS **System Preference**.
[image]

You should then be able to remap the caps lock to any key you prefer.

Comment: thanks, but i'm trying to map my dash to em dash.

Comment: lol, sorry I totally misread your question.