# How can I paste the selected text on macOS?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut

I have selected some text and I want to use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> like I do to paste the currently selected text on Linux. How can I do that on a MacBook?

Comment: Did you mean "copied", or "selected"? On Linux I'd use Shift-Insert to paste text I'd selected, but Ctrl-V to paste text I'd copied. I don't know if the former is possible on macOS - I'm hoping someone will prove me wrong!

Comment: @JohnN, selected, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979324/7222080): it's <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste selected text, without copying the text first. This might be all you need (I'm delighted it's even possible - I assumed it wasn't); however, you could if you wished remap this key combination to something more like <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> using one of the apps suggested in the answers to [Re-map keys on keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206330/re-map-keys-on-keyboard).

Comment: I'm struggling to see how that works. If I have some text selected & want to paste it somewhere, I first have to move the cursor to where I want to paste, which unselects... :/

Comment: @Tetsujin - it's most useful in a terminal: the cursor position won't change when you select text. Try selecting a command a few lines back, then press Shift-Command-V, or doing the same in vi/emacs/nano.

Comment: Cool, it is right on the mac bash command line and vim.

Comment: ah, gotcha. I guess it's unlikely to work anywhere that isn't true, couldn't work in any regular text app.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yeah, that's true, this shortcut is widely used among programmers! And the Macbook is really a arsenal!